# How to remove characters at end of text?

Tags: excel, vba

I extract data from a table in a Word document. The data is suffixed with a strange character ""(similar to bulletin). To remove this, I had used the regular expression patterns below.

```
For i = 1 To tablecount
    t_rows = ObjDoc.Tables(i).Rows.Count
    t_cols = ObjDoc.Tables(i).Columns.Count

    For j = 1 To t_cols
        t_content = ObjDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, j)
        MsgBox (t_content)
    
        t_header = format(t_content)
        MsgBox (t_header)
        count = 0

       if t_header = "ID"
           count = count +1 
    Next
Next

Function format()
    Set objexp = New RegExp
    objexp.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]" '(I want the spaces to be retained hence this pattern)
    objexp.Global = True
    objexp.IgnoreCase = True

    format = objexp.Replace(x, "")
End Function
```

The first msgbox provided the value of a data:
[image: First Msgbox output]

The second msgbox (after performing the actions inside the function format) gives:
[image: Second Msgbox output]

After performing the regular expression action, I see an additional newline/spaces (not sure though) and thereby my if condition is failing.

How can I get an output as "ID".

Comment: This looks like VBA code . If it is please change the tag. vb.net and VBA are two different languages.

Comment: i am not able to paste the strange character in the question.. it is similar to bullets in word document.

Comment: I have added the Screenshot of my output as well  for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are seeing the end of cell markers. You can remove this in the following way...

```
t_header = Left(t_content, Len(t_content) - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks . It works now. Just out of curiosity, why 2 is being subtracted from the overall length instead of 1 please?

Comment: The end of cell marker is made up of a bell character, chr(7), and a carriage return, chr(13), so it is these last 2 characters that need removing.